# java nio cpu usage issues when select() vs selectNow()

Tags: java, jvm, selector, nio

I tried to use select() vs selectNow(), the difference is high cpu usage if use selectNow(), i know that select() vs selectNow() are blocking vs non-blocking operations, so how to fix the issue? is it bugs in JDK8? or my code errors?

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    Selector selector = Selector.open();
    ServerSocketChannel channel = ServerSocketChannel.open();
    channel.configureBlocking(false);
    channel.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(9001));
    channel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);
    System.out.println("The server listened at " + LocalDateTime.now() + " on port 9001");
    Iterator<SelectionKey> iterator;
    SelectionKey key;
    while (true) {
        selector.select();          << ---- Here is the key make CPU usage!
        iterator = selector.selectedKeys().iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            key = iterator.next();
            iterator.remove();

            if (key.isAcceptable()) {
                SocketChannel sc = ((ServerSocketChannel) key.channel()).accept();
                String address = (new StringBuilder(sc.socket().getInetAddress().toString())).append(":").append(sc.socket().getPort()).toString().replace("/", "");
                sc.configureBlocking(false);
                sc.setOption(StandardSocketOptions.SO_KEEPALIVE, true);
                sc.setOption(StandardSocketOptions.SO_REUSEADDR, true);
                sc.setOption(StandardSocketOptions.TCP_NODELAY, true);
                sc.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ, address);
                System.out.println("The server accepted at " + LocalDateTime.now() + " from " + address);
            }
            if (key.isReadable()) {
                SocketChannel sc = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
                ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(8 * 1024);
                int read = sc.read(buffer);
                if (read == -1) {
                    key.channel().close();
                    key.cancel();
                } else {
                    Object object = convertByteToObject(buffer.array());
                    System.out.println("The server received at " + LocalDateTime.now() + " from " + key.attachment() + " for " + uptimeHttp.HttpRequestAddress);
                    buffer.clear();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the issue?  If you busy wait you should expect this uses 100% of a CPU or are you saying that it doesn't use 100% of a CPU?

Comment: It almost 60-80% but there are no connections when I am executing the program.

Comment: Busy waiting should use 100% of a CPU whether you have a connection or not. If you are only getting 60-80% I would be wondering why it is not higher. Perhaps the other 20-40% is in the kernel and you are not seeing that.

Comment: If you had a busy loop `while(true) { } ` you would expect it to use 100% of a CPU whether there was a TCP connection or not.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. You know that `selectNow()` doesn't block, so why are you surprised that it doesn't block?

Comment: I mean that when the program is idling, if I use selector.select() that is normal CPU usage, but if selector.selectNow() that is abnormal CPU usage about 70-80%, so I am looking for a solution to fix this issue.

Comment: Solution to fix what Issue? `select()` blocks. `selectNow()` doesn't block. If you want blocking, use `select()`. If you don't want 100% CPU usage in a spin loop, don't use '`selectNow()`, or don't put it into a spin loop. Answer is the same in both cases. Unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call a non blocking operation in a tight loop the CPU will keep iterating as fast as it can until you stop it.  This usually means you get 100% of one CPU spent executing the loop.

If you are seeing less than 100% it might be that you are looking at user CPU and the system calls might be using the rest of the CPU.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that using `selectNow()` is going to cause a tight loop as Peter suggested.  That said, `selectNow()` is an interesting option in specific situations.. such as timed-operations.  You can use `selectNow()` and a high precision timer to mandate that the operation occurs at a specific frequency.  Thats a pretty specific situation tho.

Therefore, if you want to use `selectNow()` you are going to have to pair it with `Thread.sleep()` or some equivalent.

Comment: Noted, but now I am the status:
You have reached your question limit
Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See the Help Center to learn more.  <  ----  How to fix it?

Comment: @AndyChan you probably have to start selecting answers or deleting old questions.